# Dismissing a View Controller that was reached by a custom push segue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I am trying to dismiss a view controller or otherwise go back to the previous VC on a VC reached by a custom view controller (SWRevealViewController push segue). I understand that since it was not presented modally, I can't use **self.dismissViewController**. However, I also tried **self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)**
to no avail.

[image: Segue Example]

```
@IBAction func saveBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (diffPerc.text != "" && diffDays.text != "" && eqCost.text != "" && fixedCost.text != "" && pwrUsg.text != "" && pwrCost.text != "" && poolCost.text != "" && variableCost.text != "") {
        if
        (Int(diffPerc.text!)! >= 0 && Int(diffPerc.text!)! < 10000 && Int(diffDays.text!)! > 0){
        print("should do calculation")
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "advanced")
        defaults.setInteger(Int(diffPerc.text!)!, forKey: "p")
        defaults.setInteger(Int(diffDays.text!)!, forKey: "n")
        defaults.setFloat(Float(eqCost.text!)!, forKey: "eqCost")
        defaults.setFloat(Float(fixedCost.text!)!, forKey: "fixedCost")

        let pwr: Float = Float(pwrUsg.text!)! * Float(pwrCost.text!)!
        defaults.setFloat(pwr, forKey: "pwr")
        defaults.setFloat(Float(pwrUsg.text!)!, forKey: "pwrUsg")
        defaults.setFloat(Float(pwrCost.text!)!, forKey: "pwrCost")
        defaults.setFloat(Float(variableCost.text!)!, forKey: "variableCost")
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }} else {
        presentError("Can't Save Data", m: "Please make sure all text boxes are filled, or choose 'Simple Calculator'")
    }
}
```

Could somebody give me some feedback?

Comment: Don't you just call `revealToggleAnimated:` or whatever?

Comment: Could you tell me how I would code that in Swift?

Comment: Hi Jacobo! I am not too sure as to why this is happening. Can you please upload a code snippet or send a link to your project?

Comment: Thanks Kevin.. Just added an attachment and part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer, although I'm not quite sure why the previous wasn't working and this is.

I used **performSegueWithIdentifier** on the new View Controller going back to the initial one.

Thanks for all your help.